# Local webpage/website cannot be displayed

Tags: 13.04, apache2

This location could not be displayed prompts when i open the folder containing my website files in /home/html/mywebsite. It says you do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "html", when i type mywebsite.com it says forbidden.

Can someone help me how to solve this problem, i dont know how to resolve restrictions in ubuntu im a windows user just trying out ubuntu for our linux project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `sudo chmod -R 755 /home/html` in a terminal then try again.

Every file has permission. You can see permission using `ls -l` in relevant folder

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 dedunu dedunu 4096 Sep  3 19:48 Desktop
```

After `d` first three characters `rwx` means owner of this file can read, write and execute.

Then next `r-x` means group can read and execute.

Then next `r-x` means others can read and execute.

Comment: Thanks! It worked :) i was really puzzled how to solve it. I just did chmod -R 755 /home/html/* to take the ownership of the files i just copied.

Comment: You have change the permission but you down have ownership to get ownership use "chown -R username:username /home/html"